# Rewriting System.out.print statements a bit easier

Tags: java, outputstream

I was wondering if there was an easier way of rewriting this code.

```
System.out.print(x);
System.out.print("+" +y);
System.out.println("=" +sum);
```

The value of x is 10 and y is 5 so the output displays as:

```
10+5=15
```

Is there is a quicker way to do this, that is, a way to do this without using the print statement three times?

Comment: What do you mean, "without copying and pasting all the time"?  What are you copying and pasting?

Comment: this might be one of the options https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-java-programming-part-1-hkustx-comp102-1x

Comment: Asking for resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11):

```
System.out.print(x + "+" + y + "=" + sum);
```

Comment: This is "easy" even though formating has advantages ;)

Comment: This is probably the most concise and type-agnostic approach.

Answer (score 9):

if all ints

```
System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n", x, y, sum);
// or perhaps better
System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n", x, y, x + y);
```

If floating point:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f + %.2f = %.2f%n", x, y, sum);
// or perhaps better
System.out.printf("%.2f + %.2f = %.2f%n", x, y, x + y);
```

Comment: You may also want to have the classical sysout();

Comment: what's the difference between printf and print? Are there any advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: @tam `printf` will allow you to format your output. That is the case with this answer.

Comment: If you do this very often in your program, this might be the way to go, because it really reduces concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d + %d = %d", x, y, sum));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply without using another variable for the sum and in one line, you will just use:

```
System.out.print(x + "+" + y + "=" + (x+y));
```